# Request an embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have some problem with Hibernate.

I have a table withtout Id column. So i used an embedded id to configure a couple of columns as Id. But when i query on one of these 2 Ids, I don't receive all the values.

The table :

```
CODE_ACTION | CODE_AVANCEMENT | DATE_AVANCEMENT | COUT
----------------------------------------------------------
A0000001    | Engagée         | 09/09/11        | 2400
A0000002    | Terminée        | 05/10/12        | 2700
A0000002    | Engagée         | 05/10/12        | 2700
A0000003    | Terminée        | 06/06/10        | 0
```

etc.

My entity

```
@Entity
@Component
@Data
@Table(name = "F_AVANCEMENT_ACTION")
public class AvancementActionDtw {

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // FIELDS
  // --------------------------------------------------------  

  @Id
  private AvancementActionDtwPk id;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "DATE_AVANCEMENT", nullable = false)
  private Date dateAvancement;

  @Column(name = "COUT", nullable = true)
  private Integer coutAction;

}
```

My embedded id

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "codeAction", "codeAvancement" })
public class AvancementActionDtwPk  implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Fields
  // --------------------------------------------------------  

  @Column(name = "CODE_ACTION", nullable = false)
  private String codeAction;

  @Column(name = "CODE_AVANCEMENT", nullable = false)
  private String codeAvancement;

}
```

EDIT : the modified embedded id

```
@Data
@Embeddable
// @EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "codeAction", "codeAvancement" })
public class AvancementActionDtwPk  implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Fields
  // --------------------------------------------------------  

  @Column(name = "CODE_ACTION", nullable = false)
  private String codeAction;

  @Column(name = "CODE_AVANCEMENT", nullable = false)
  private String codeAvancement;

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Constructors
  // --------------------------------------------------------

  public AvancementActionDtwPk() {
  }

  public AvancementActionDtwPk(String codeAction, String codeAvancement) {
    this.codeAction = codeAction;
    this.codeAvancement = codeAvancement;
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Equals and HashCode
  // --------------------------------------------------------

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 31). // two randomly chosen prime numbers
        append(this.codeAction).append(this.codeAvancement).toHashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof AvancementActionDtwPk)) return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;

    AvancementActionDtwPk pk = (AvancementActionDtwPk) obj;
    return this.codeAction.equals(pk.codeAction) && this.codeAvancement.equals(pk.codeAvancement);
  }

}
```

The DAO

```
@Repository
@Component
public interface AvancementActionDtwDao extends JpaRepository<AvancementActionDtw, AvancementActionDtwPk> {


  @Query("from AvancementActionDtw where id.codeAction = :codeAction and id.codeAvancement = :codeAvancement")
  List<AvancementActionDtw> findAvancementActionDtw(@Param("codeAction") String codeAction,
      @Param("codeAvancement") String codeAvancement);


  @Query("from AvancementActionDtw where id.codeAction = :codeAction")
  List<AvancementActionDtw> findAvancementActionDtw(@Param("codeAction") String codeAction);

}
```

If i call

```
findAvancementActionDtw("A0000002")
```

I only get the 2nd entry <"A0000002"; "Engagée">
If I explicitly set the 2nd parameter

```
findAvancementActionDtw("A0000002", "Terminée")
```

I have no result

I would like to know where I'm wrong ?

PS : The data are in an Oracle Database

Comment: Can you specify the exception you get if any..??

Comment: I don't have an exception, only the results are wrong. I think that come from my embedded id, but just an intuition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact my SQL Developer was not on the same BDD that my application...

Stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

From JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 11.1.15 EmbeddedId Annotation:

> The `EmbeddedId` annotation is applied to a persistent field or
>   property of an entity class or mapped superclass to denote a composite
>   primary key that is an embeddable class. The embeddable class must be
>   annotated as `Embeddable`.  Relationship mappings defined within an
>   embedded id class are not supported.
>
> There must be only one `EmbeddedId` annotation and no `Id` annotation
>   when the `EmbeddedId` annotation is used.

I guess you would need to use @EmbeddedId to make it work:

```java
@Entity
@Component
@Data
@Table(name = "F_AVANCEMENT_ACTION")
public class AvancementActionDtw {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AvancementActionDtwPk id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This sounds right but then why does it work for _findAvancementActionDtw_ and not in _findAvancementActionDtw_

Comment: I tried with **EmbeddedId** and after with **Id**, the result is the same :(

Comment: Strange. Maybe `é` character has something in common with it? What if you replace `@EqualsAndHashCode` with plain `public boolean equals (Object o)` and `public int hashCode()` methods? No-arg constructor is also required.

Comment: @wypieprz I update the class with your recommandations, same result